# Looking to Update my Web app from Vaadin 6.8 to 7.x

Tags: performance, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a huge web app running in vaadin 6.8 looking to upgrade it to latest version as of its more stability and improved.  How much effort it will take to achieve it.
For an approx exact idea 700+ classes (Files) and most are of 14000+ lines
any further suggestion to this.

Comment: I think only you can answer this. If the 14000 lines are mainly business logic then it will not be a big thing to move the to vaadin 7. But if these lines are UI stuff, then it might take longer. Probably you should migrate 2-3 representative classes over to vaadin 7, so you get a impression what effort it will take for the whole bunch.

Comment: obviously UI is involve and you can say 30% of a class is of UI components. So Ihave to spare 2 months to do it